# Привязка RelativeSource к GridViewColumn

Tags: wpf, binding, xaml

Делаю вот такой столбец для `ListView` c `TextBox'ом` внутри и пытаюсь привязать свойство `Width TextBox'a` к одноименному полю `GridViewColumn'a`.

```
<GridViewColumn Width="100">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=GridViewColumn}, Path=Width}" Text="SomeText"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

В результате выполнения никакой привязки не происходит. В Output выводится следующее сообщение:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot
> find source for binding with reference
> 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
> AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn',
> AncestorLevel='1''.
> BindingExpression:Path=Width;
> DataItem=null; target element is
> 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property
> is 'Width' (type 'Double')

Если же задать имя для `GridViewColumn`, и сделать привязку через `ElementName`, то все работает. Почему не срабатывает первый вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не срабатывает потому, что поиск в `FindAncestor` идёт вверх по визуальному дереву до границы инкапсуляции. `DataTemplate` является такой границей, ведь он может быть определён отдельно, например, в ресурсах.

Comment: И как быть в двнной ситуации? Есть способы решения не задавая при этом имя столбцу?

Comment: @Данил: Не уверен, сработает ли, но: если положить в корень `DataTemplate`'а `Grid`, не будет ли он автоматом иметь полную ширину? (Проверьте, установив цветной фон.) Потом можно привязаться к его ширине.

Comment: @VlandD: к сожалению нет. Grid получает ширину по содержимому